# Jenkins Job Builder: variable substitution in !include path

Tags: jenkins, yaml, jenkins-job-builder

Given a project like this

```
- project:
    name: my-project
    type:
      - apple
```

and a job-template like this

```
- job-template:
    project-type: freestyle
    name: '{name}-build-{type}'
    builders:
      !include: "builders/{type}.yml"
```

I get the error
`IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'builders/{type}.yml'`

which makes me thing that JJB isn't willing to do variable subtitution in the path of an included file.

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks.